# How can I copy an item from references to disk? (c#)

Tags: c#, copy, reference

For example, I have a flash movie in my references. How do I copy this to a location outside of the application?

Comment: What do you mean with "in my references" ?

Comment: I think he means in the project references

Comment: How do you get a flash movie in the project references?

Comment: @fretje is right. Please try to elaborate your problem or what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have it as an embedded resource, you'd do something like:

```
public static void WriteResourceToDisk(Assembly assembly, 
                                       string resource,
                                       string file)
{
    using (Stream input = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Resource name not found");
        }
        using (Stream output = File.Create(file))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
WriteResourceToDisk(typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly, 
                    "Foo.Bar.FlashFile.swf", "file.swf");
```

(Where `Foo.Bar.FlashFile.swf` is the path to the resource.)

Comment: where 'Foo.Bar.' - is a path to the resource.

Comment: I want to suppress this feeling but don't you find it *annoying* to see someone posting a suspense question and when you ask more information, there is just dark silence! (no comments, no edits, no accepted answers)

Comment: Yes, it's annoying. Then again, many things are annoying in life :)